# Trigger GitHub actions' workflow when some workflows themselves change

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Ι want to create a workflow that is triggered when some **other** `.github/workflow` files change.

I want to monitor all the `.github/workflow` starting with a specific prefix. i.e. `foo_`, as in `.github/workflow/foo_1.yaml` , `.github/workflow/foo_2.yaml` etc.

Is it possible to specify such a pattern on the workflow trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it natively using the [push event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push) trigger, with the [paths](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-only-when-a-push-affects-specific-files) subtype.

**Example:**

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '.github/workflows/foo_**'
```

*Note that if there is another trigger event configured in the workflow, it can start by being triggering by one **OR** the other (not AND).*